# C# отрисовываются только два PictureBox

Tags: c#, изображения, picturebox

Есть несколько PictureBox, которые перерисовываются 25 раз в секунду. Проблема в том, что изображение отображается только на первых двух, для которых было запущено обновление 25 раз в секунду. Как можно решить эту проблему? Проверял и в WinForms, и в WPF - результат одинаков.

Вот кусочек кода:

```
redrawTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerTick, null, 1000, 40);
...
private void TimerTick(object stateInfo)
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox.Image))
        g.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName), 0, 0,
            pictureBox.Image.Width, pictureBox.Image.Height);
}
```

Отрисовывались изображения по размеру меньше или равные размеру bitmap, на который они отрисовывались. Кстати, может кто-то знает быстрый метод сжатия картинки? Стандартный очень долгий.

Если быть конкретней - есть 4 picturebox, на 3 из которых отрисовываются различные изображения, а четвёртый клонирует на свой bitmap изображение из одного из этих трёх. Было выявлено, что при не отрисовке  изображения на preview-picturebox, основной picturebox успешно клонирует и выводит с них изображение. Во всех четырёх picturebox в image были bitmap одинакового размера, загнанные в режиме zoom, так как превосходили размерами сами picturebox.

Answer (score 6):

Прежде всего, попробуйте в конце функции-таймера добавить вызов `pictureBox.Invalidate()` или `pictureBox.Refresh()`, чтобы заставить картинку перерисоваться.

Если не поможет, то читайте далее. Точно не знаю, чего именно не хватает вашей программе, поэтому предлагаю несколько вариантов.

### Вариант 1. Если вы "уперлись" в пропускную способность ввода-вывода.

1. `Image.FromFile(fileName)` возвращает Bitmap, который также требуется закрывать. Добавьте второй using в код.
2. Операция чтения файла с диска - довольно "тяжелая", а выполняете вы ее в потоке UI. Отсюда - "подвисания" этого потока 100 раз в секунду. Лучше бы делать это в фоновом потоке.

Получается код вроде такого:

```
private async void TimerTick(object unused)
{
    using (var image = await Task.Run(() => System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName)))
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox.Image))
        g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, pictureBox.Image.Width, pictureBox.Image.Height);
}
```

### Вариант 2. Если вы "уперлись" в способность процессора перегонять туда-сюда байты.

Обратите внимание, как происходит отображение картинки на экране монитора.

1. Сначала вы загружаете ее из файла.
2. Потом - копируете ее в другую картинку.
3. Потом PictureBox внутри себя еще раз выполняет копирование.

Если дело действительно в скорости работы процессора/системной шины/памяти, то от одного копирования можно избавиться.

Дело в том, что если загружать картинку не по имени файла, а из потока - то, при условии что картинка в файле находится в допустимом формате, картинка будет всегда оставаться "синхронизированной" с файлом.

Какие форматы допустимы, я уже не помню, но 32-битный BMP в таком режиме точно поддерживается.

```
var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename);
pictureBox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
// а в таймере - только Invalidate()
```

### Вариант 3. Если ничего не помогает

Можно использовать не 4 таймера, а 1, который будет обновлять картинки по-очереди, если вы еще не сделали этого. В таком случае картинки будут обновляться равномерно, даже ценой "просадки" производительности.

Если вы используете асинхронный таймер (наподобие того, который в варианте 1), имеет смысл сделать ему защиту от повторного срабатывания, чтобы одна и та же картинка не загружалась несколько раз одновременно. Это не поможет удержаться на уровне 25 кадров в секунду - зато поможет снижать частоту кадров без тормозов и подвисаний.

Кстати о тормозах и лагах. Имеет смысл плавно снижать частоту таймера вместо простого выкидывания кадров - для повышения плавности движения. Измеряете время, затраченное на загрузку кадра при помощи `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`, берете максимальное время за последние 5 кадров - и выставляете его в качестве периода таймера.

Варианты 1 и 2 можно попытаться объединить - надо создать картинку на основе `MemoryStream`, а в него уже перечитывать данные из файла в фоновом потоке (не в таймере!). Точнее, лучше перечитывать в его внутренний буфер, не трогая сам поток. (Опять-таки, это будет работать только для 32х-битного BMP) Как-то так:

```
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
pictureBox.Image = FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer));

...

using (new stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
pictureBox.Invalidate();
```

Еще вопрос: а сами файлы точно успевают обновляться 25 раз в секунду? Если нет, то имеет смысл наблюдать за файлами с помощью `FileSystemWatcher`, и обновлять картинки только после изменений в файлах.

---

Ну и вопрос напоследок: откуда вообще берутся на диске файлы, которые обновляются 25 раз в секунду? Нельзя ли их получить минуя диск?

Кстати, нельзя ли их положить на диск в памяти (т.н. ramdrive)?

Answer (score 0):

Задачка для видеонаблюдения если не ошибаюсь? Клейте 4 кадра в один picturebox.

Давно не работал с WinForms, надо бы поэкспериментировать, но моё субъективное мнение подсказывает что склеить 4 кадра в один и вывести в один контрол будет быстрее чем выводить 4 кадра в 4 контрола. Поправьте меня если я ошибаюсь

Comment: @Dmitry, если автор упирается в "пропускную способность" WinAPI - то надо не кадры клеить, а использовать DirectX. Если же WinAPI тут ни при чем - то клеить кадры бессмысленно.